# continue ALLWAYS Illegal in switch in JS but break works fine

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, loops, switch-statement

```
switch ("B")
{
case "A":
    break;
case "B":
    continue;
case "C":
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

simple correct code in C++, but when made in javascript in stable chrome it just throws an error "Illegal continue statement", looks like continue statement is just disallowed in switch in javascript... Heard about return but it just returns and doesnt continue... So is there a way to continue switch in js?

Comment: You need to explain what you want this code to do, because `continue` is not defined for `switch` (no matter how much you wish it to be), and we cannot divine your requirements from an example of a language feature that does not exist.

Comment: I have worked out — after much effort — that you wish to **jump** to the next case in the list (you keep calling it "break", but "break" means to leave the switch entirely). There is simply no syntax to do that, as I discuss in my answer.

Comment: This is unfortunate, since I have encountered an instance of a data structure that would benefit from this sort of behavior. `obj: { dims: [...], vars: [..., atts: [...], ...], atts: [...] }` , where I use a path to determine a part being referenced: dims.name, atts.name, vars.name.atts.attName, where often both atts are processed the same, because they have the same internal properties. i.e. `switch (_path[0]) { case 'dims': break; case 'vars': ...if (_path[2] === 'atts') continue; /* on to 'atts'*/ break; case 'atts': break; }`    Alas, must simply resort to trusty if/elses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`continue` has absolutely nothing to do with `switch`es, not in Javascript [and not in C++](http://ideone.com/w02zJE):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 0;
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            continue;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            y = 4;
    }
}
```

> error: continue statement not within a loop

If you wish to break out of the case, use `break`; otherwise, allow the case to fall through:

```
switch ("B")
{
    case "A":
        break;
    case "B":
    case "C":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If you're looking for a *shortcut* to *jump* to the next case then, no, you can't do this.

```
switch ("B")
{
    case "A":
        break;
    case "B":
        if (something) {
           continue; // nope, sorry, can't do this; use an else
        }

        // lots of code
    case "C":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: LOL I don't know C++ at all so I had to take the OP's word for it... lmao

Comment: It should be noted that using `continue` in `switch` is OK as long as your `switch` is inside a loop. In that case, `continue` will actually `break` the `switch`.

Comment: @klerik: It'll do more than `break` the `switch`; it'll skip over _everything_ in the current loop iteration, and confuse your fellow programmers. In that instance you have a `continue` in a loop, so to say that it's "in" a `switch` is misleading. Anyway I wouldn't say it's "OK" because it is spaghetti code.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I din't meant to offend you, I just wanted to improve your answer. I was trying to find out whether I can use `continue` (for my loop) inside `switch` (since 'similiar' `break` will not work). And there is no spaghetti in this, It's just another use case. I've never used single 'goTo' stuff in my life.

Comment: @klerik: No offence taken! I'm simply disagreeing!

Answer (score 13):

I believe you can emulate what you want by using a labeled infinite loop:

```
var a = "B";
loop: while( true ) {
    switch (a)
    {
    case "A":
        break loop;
    case "B":
        a = "C";
        continue loop;
    case "C":
        break loop;
    default:
        break loop;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should consider expressing what you want in some other way.

Even if you can pull this off, it would be a huge WTF. Just use if else if.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you meant is:

```
switch ("B")
{
    case "A":
        break;
    case "B":
    case "C":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

There is no need for `continue`. When B comes, it will move on to C.

Comment: Yes, I meant this and I know about this but I need this emptyiness as continue statement because I need to break; in all conditions in case "B" and only in one condition to continue, continuing as emptyness would require tons of garbage code to check it all before breaking and not guarantee that there won't be a case with unintentional continuing and not breaking

Comment: In that case, why don't you just put a `break;` in `B`.

Comment: because I also need continue there, conditionally, before break as I wrote above.

Comment: `continue` is meant to be in loops in order to skip execution of a particular item in a list. What does it have to do with a switch

Comment: it have to do the continuing in switch if you ask this, and continue in C++ is meant to be used in switches btw

Comment: In JS also, you can use a `continue`, in switch, provided your switch statement is inside a loop

Comment: If you copy my code into chrome console it would give a syntaxerror immediately saying you can't use it in switch.

Comment: Its because there is no outer loop

Comment: @Owyn: No, [`continue` is _not_ meant to be used in switches in C++](http://ideone.com/w02zJE). Not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use it in switch inside loops, in this cases break/continue are a useful combo

take a look at this example

```
var array = [1, 2, "I am a string", function(){}, {}, 1,2,3]
for(let i in array){
    switch(typeof array[i]) {
    case "number":
        array[i] += " I was a number"
        break; // break from the switch but go on in the for-loop
               // ie. go to *put esclamation mark*
    case "function":
        array[i] = "function"
        // fall through
    default:
        array[i] = `this is a ${JSON.stringify(array[i])} object`
        break; // also here goes to *put esclamation mark*
    case "string":
        continue; // continue with the next iteration of the loop
                  // ie. do not put exclamation mark in this case
    }
    array[i] += "!" // *put esclamation mark*
}
/*
array will become
[ "1 I was a number!", "2 I was a number!", "I am a string", "this is a \"function\" object!", "this is a {} object!", "1 I was a number!", "2 I was a number!", "3 I was a number!" ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

A switch case without the `break` statement will "fall through" (as it's called) to the next. Omitting `break` will make the code behave like you say you expect as it is the default/implicit behavior of the switch statement.

The use of the `continue` statement is reserved for loops where what it does is actually slightly different from what you want; it will break the current iteration of the loop and continue to the next one, reevaluating the loop condition.

Comment: So there is no shortcut to "falling through" in switches?

Comment: @Owyn: Falling through is the default behaviour — you do it by not writing `break`. No, you can't "jump" to the next case. And don't give me this nonsense "I also need it to `break`" because that's a total contradiction

Answer (score -1):

Continue may only refer to the loop.
It can't be used inside the switch statement.
What behavior do you expect from it, anyway?

Comment: I expect it to go check next case statement below one with continue

Comment: what about just not putting 'break' keyword?

Comment: then it won't break and I also need it to break.

Comment: @Owyn: What the hell are you talking about? You either want it to break, or you want it to fall through to the next case. How could you possibly do _both_?

Comment: both at two different conditions inside the case not at once

Comment: It *is* possible to use continue in a switch statement - if - the swtich statement is inside a loop.